# How can I escape single quotation marks using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a code as below,

```
<% content_for(:tag_params) { "[#{@tag.site.name.to_s.html_safe}.#{@tag.name.to_s.html_safe}]" } %>
```

which comes out as below;

```
[sitename.tagname]
```

I want to surround it with single quotation marks / double quotation marks as below;

```
['sitename.tagname']
["sitename.tagname"]
```

and I've tried the following codes, but none of them worked.

```
# 1. Tried to escape the single quote using backslash.
<% content_for(:tag_params) { "[\'#{@tag.site.name.to_s.html_safe}.#{@tag.name.to_s.html_safe}\']" } %>
# outcome -> [&#39;sitename.tagname&#39;]

# 2. If I don't escape the single quote, I got the same outcome as above.
<% content_for(:tag_params) { "['#{@tag.site.name.to_s.html_safe}.#{@tag.name.to_s.html_safe}']" } %>
# outcome -> [&#39;sitename.tagname&#39;]

# 3. I tried using %Q[] and %(), which also gave me the same result.
<% content_for(:tag_params) { %('#{@tag.site.name.to_s.html_safe}.#{@tag.name.to_s.html_safe}') } %>
<% content_for(:tag_params) { %Q['#{@tag.site.name.to_s.html_safe}.#{@tag.name.to_s.html_safe}'] } %>
# outcome -> [&#39;sitename.tagname&#39;]
```

What can I do to surround the values successfully with a single/double quotation marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried with `irb`:

```rb
"['#{'sitename'}.#{'tagname'}']" # => "['sitename.tagname']"
```

So you could change code like this:

```rb
<% content_for(:tag_params) { "['#{@tag.site.name}.#{@tag.name}']".html_safe } %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already tried that, and got this on the browser;
[&#39;sitename.tagname&#39;]
Is there any way I can avoid the single quotation mark turning into &#39?

Comment: You could add `html_safe`: `"['#{'sitename'}.#{'tagname'}']".html_safe`

Comment: Ahh! I had the ".html_safe" in the wrong place! Quoting the whole thing, and putting ".html_safe" at the end solved the problem!! Thank you so much, eux!!!

Comment: Only works when you are controlling `@tag.site.name` and `@tag.name`. Otherwise, users might provide names that are not HTML safe and should not be treated as such.

Comment: Sorry, What if I wanted to quote it with double quotation mark as below?
["sitename.tagname"]

Comment: Never mind, with double quotation marks, I was able to escape with just using \. Thanks for all your help.